# How is the Big O of this function O(n^3)?

Tags: python, big-o

I am stuck on this Big O notation on how it is supposed to be O(n^3). Where did my thought process go wrong?

I know that a nested for loop is O(n^2) and that the while loop is probably a O(nlogn) function because the for loop is a O(n) function and the value for the while loop is being multiplied by two which makes it O(logn). That being said, the answer is stated to be O(n^3) and I'm confused how this came to be unless the recursive part of the function has something to do with it?

```py
def do_stuff2(n, x=1.23):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    val = 1
    for i in range(n//2):
        for j in range(n//4):
            x += 2*x + j/2 + i*1.2
    while val <= n:
        for i in range(n):
            x += val**2 + i//2
        val *= 2
    x += do_stuff2(n - 1, x/2)
    return x
```

I believe that the x does not affect the big o notation because it is a constant because it is not used in deciding how many times any of the loops loop.

So again, I expected the output of the function to be O(n^2), but the actual output is O(n^3)

Comment: The recursion itself is O(n). Then within that you have a for loop inside a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has two nested for loops, that's `O(n^2)`:

```
for i in range(n//2):
    for j in range(n//4):
        x += 2*x + j/2 + i*1.2
```

But on top of that, your `do_stuff2()` function takes an argument `n` and calls itself until `n <= 0`, meaning that's one more `O(n)`.